# nginx proxy to different path

Tags: nginx, proxy

I've read through the documentation for nginx's HttpProxyModule, but I can't figure this out:

I want it so that if someone visits, for example `http://ss.example.com/1339850978`, nginx will proxy them `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxx/screenshots/1339850978.png`.

If I was to just use this line in my config file:
`proxy_pass http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxx/screenshots/;`,
then they would have to append the `.png` themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `proxy_pass` with a rewrite directive:

```
rewrite /([^/]+) /$1.png break;
proxy_pass http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxx/screenshots/;
```

Comment: This didn't quite work but after some experimentation I found this was fine:    
    `rewrite         /(.*) /u/70152/screenshots/$1.png break;`    
    `proxy_pass      http://dl.dropbox.com/;`

Comment: @DavidRobertson, I am sorry it did not work. will try to fix it as soon as I can get to test the rules. Thank you for the points.